# Getting key from an array

Tags: php

I have an array called $array which contains entries like this:

```
Array ( 
  [2340] => Array ( 
     [cv] => Array ( 
       [size] => 317613
       [c] => 3 ) ) 
  [16410] => Array ( 
     [cv] => Array ( 
       [size] => 119808 
       [c] => 1 ) ) 
)
```

I am using the below and everything works except the first value - I need it to display 2340 in the first iteration and then 16410 in the second where I have $row[0] below:

```
foreach ($array as $row) {
  print $row[0];
  print($row[cv][size]);
  print($row[cv][c]);
}
```

How do I access that first ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this...

```
foreach ($array as $first_value => $row) {
    print $first_value;
    print($row[cv][size]);
    print($row[cv][c]);
}
```

... instead (as 'first value' you're talking about is actually an index of the element processed).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 array_keys( $array )[ $idx ]
```

where `$array` is your array, and `$idx` is the index you want to access

E.g.:

```
 echo array_keys( $array )[0]
```

for the index of 1st element

Answer (score 0):

Change your foreach:

```
foreach ($array as $id => $row) {
    echo $id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because what you have is an associative array(hash table), you need to pass another param to the foreach statement, so you can have the key of the element in anohter var.

```
foreach ($array as $key =>  $row) {
  print $key;
  print $row[0];
  print($row[cv][size]);
  print($row[cv][c]);
}
```

In the $key variable you have the value of the associative key of each active element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

**This should work**

```
foreach ($array as $key => $row) {
print $key;
print $row[0];
print($row[cv][size]);
print($row[cv][c]);
}
```